# How spite separate array images from one array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my explode function

```
$array = explode("/(?:\<img[\s].*?src=)(?:\"|\')(.*)?(?:\'|\")/", $others[0]->post_desc);
          print_r($array);
```

$others[0]->post_desc this variables have 3 images

I've a result  [image]

But I want separate  array images

array[0] have one image and array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7765.png) have one image and array[2] have other image

Comment: can you provide what is `$others[0]->post_desc` array exactly?

Comment: $others[0]->post_desc array have exactly result 

[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7765.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H08nE.png

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean there is binary data in `$others[0]->post_desc` or what? if you run this line of code `var_dump($others[0]->post_desc);` what would be the output?